# Is it possible to calculate the SQL Server sql_handle for a given SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server

The following site mentions the `sql_handle` is a MD5 hash of the entire batch text

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/2-0-sql-handle-and-plan-handle-explained/ba-p/383204

However, I'm unable to calculate it manually. From `dm_exec_query_stats` we determine the following statement has the following `sql_handle`.

```
SQL: (@P1 bigint)SELECT NID MimeTypeID, Name FROM DDocumentClass WHERE Type = @P1
SQL_HANDLE: 0x02000000CA17931BEF7F24A1787BF580EA365A56408697B30000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The following Ruby script calculates the MD5.

```
require 'digest'

sql1 = 'SELECT NID MimeTypeID, Name FROM DDocumentClass WHERE Type = @P1'
sql2 = '(@P1 bigint)SELECT NID MimeTypeID, Name FROM DDocumentClass WHERE Type = @P1'

puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest sql1
puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest sql2
```

Output:

```
81707e73438befe82957c766dca86799
2652dc1d05e927ac7c5bfc985a3d1483
```

There must be more to the algorithm.

We can calculate Oracle's SQL_ID, I'm hoping to be able to also calculate SQL Server's SQL_HANDLE.

Comment: Partial answer.

The unicode string will be using UCS-2 encoding - likely string literals in Ruby use some different encoding by default.

Then it looks like this provides *part* of the handle. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK1B9.png

Comment: Thank you! That gets us part way. Still having issues programmatically performing the MD5 hash in Ruby even with a UTF-8 to UCS-2 conversion. Just doesn't compute.

Answer (score 8):

The 44-byte `sql_handle` has the following components (in order):

1. **4 bytes:** Byte-reversed integer code for the target cache e.g.

   - `0x02000000` (2) for SQL Plans (`CACHESTORE_SQLCP`)
   - `0x03000000` (3) for Object Plans (`CACHESTORE_OBJCP`)
2. **4 bytes:** Byte-reversed integer *object id*

   - For adhoc and prepared SQL this is an [internal hash of the batch text](https://www.sql.kiwi/2020/10/sqlhandle-and-sql-server-batch-text-hash.html) as returned by `@@PROCID` or `objectid` in `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`.
3. **16 bytes:** MD5 hash of the batch text including (parameter definitions) prefix, if present.
4. **20 bytes** `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`